# How to parse the data which we got in the console in iPhone. I want the result from that data to be displayed in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xml

I am new to iPhone development. I invoked sap web-service wsdl from iPhone and I had received as an xml file in console. But now I want the particular data with in that xml file must be displayed.With in that xml me having the particular data which I want but I don't know how to display only that particular data from that xml file. Can anyone suggest me an answer or let someone help me in doing so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try one of This

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project